# How do you get the column order for the Grid in Vaadin 23?

Tags: grid, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I would like to save the column order the user has set/changed when they come back to the same page in Grid.

I read this issue -
[How do you get the column order for the Grid in Vaadin 14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836408/how-do-you-get-the-column-order-for-the-grid-in-vaadin-14)

Is this issue fixed in Vaadin 23?
If there is any solution, please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
this is possible with flow 23.
Here the listeners I use to save column order and width

```
protected List<Grid.Column<T>> newColOrder= null;
grid.addColumnReorderListener((event) ->
{
    newColOrder= event.getColumns();
    persistColumns();
});
grid.addColumnResizeListener((event) ->
{
    persistColumns();
});
```

And the persistColumn method:

```
List<Grid.Column<T>> cols= newColOrder != null ? newColOrder : grid.getColumns();
for (Grid.Column<T> col : cols)
{
    boolean isHidden= !col.isVisible();
    String colWidth= col.getWidth();
    String colID= col.getKey();
    gcs.add(new GridColumnStatus(isHidden, colWidth, colID));
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I am getting a compiler error "The method getColumns() is undefined for the type ComponentEvent" from the line newColOrder=event.getColumns();

Comment: How do you define the grid? https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.0.7/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html#getColumns()

Comment: Andre,
I added the extra line to cast event type to ColumnReorderEvent as below; event type is ComponentEvent by default.
grid.addColumnReorderListener((event) -> {
        ColumnReorderEvent aColumnReorderEvent = (ColumnReorderEvent)event;
 List<Grid.Column> newColOrder = aColumnReorderEvent.getColumns();
   ...
}
Thank you for your comment. :)